# Oledb Excel select max(ColumnA)?

Tags: excel, select, max, oledb

I have values like below in excel sheet.(No Column Header)

```
COLUMN A
5 
9 
7 
13
8
```

i want to  this with Oledb Query in VBNET or C#;

```
select MAX(A) from [Sheet1$]
```

But get Error !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Since tagged Excel I'll go for:

```
=MAX(Sheet1!A:A)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to vbnet or C# oledb connection string.  this code not run in connectionstring